# Calculating expected value of non-empty chambers. What is wrong in my solution?

Tags: probability, solution-verification, expected-value

Instering $5$ different balls to $12$  different chambers, all the options are equally probabable. Let $X$ be the number of non-empty chambers, calculate $\mathbb{E}[X]$

I know that $\mathbb{E}(X)=\sum_{t \in R_{X}} t \cdot \mathbb{P}(X=t)$ so I just need to calculate $\mathbb{P}(X=t)$ for every $1\leq t \leq 5$
$$\mathbb{P}(X=1)= \frac{1}{12^4}$$
$$\mathbb{P}(X=2)= \frac{11 \cdot 2^3}{12^4}$$
$$\mathbb{P}(X=3)= \frac{11\cdot 10\cdot 3^2}{12^4}$$
$$\mathbb{P}(X=4)= \frac{11\cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot4}{12^4}$$
$$\mathbb{P}(X=5)= \frac{11\cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot8}{12^4}$$

now I just substitute this values in the expression $$\mathbb{E}(X)=\sum_{t \in R_{X}} t \cdot \mathbb{P}(X=t)$$ but I am not getting the right answer. I assume I have mistake in develop the expressions above. The options are:

A. $\displaystyle \frac{161051}{20736}$

B. $\displaystyle \frac{161051}{248832}$

C. $\displaystyle \frac{87781}{20736}$

D. $\displaystyle \frac{87781}{248832}$

Comment: Whatever does this mean "none empty chambers"? If you have $5$ balls and $12$ chambers, wouldn't at least $7$ chambers be empty (with the possibility to have $8$, $9$, $10$ or $11$ empty chambers)?

Comment: Based on the expectation calculations, I believe OP means 'non empty chambers' instead.

Comment: @masiewpao Quite possible - I would therefore expect an edit by the OP.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Yes I agree

Comment: @masiewpao I corrected it srry, I meant to non

Comment: Should say:  I don't understand your probabilities.  Do they even sum to $1$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to say, Linearity of expectation works well here.

The probability that a given chamber is non-empty is $$p=1-\left(\frac {11}{12}\right)^5=\frac {87781}{248832}$$.

As there are $12$ chambers, the answer is then $$12p=12\times \frac {87781}{248832}=\boxed {\frac {87781}{20736}}$$

Comment: sorry for the delay but I go over this question again and I not feel comfortable with the expression $\frac{11}{12}^5$ what is it's meaning? why do I have to power it by level of $5$?

Comment: @Sagigever   Fix a chamber.  The probability that a given ball is in a different one is $\frac {11}{12}$.  The probability that all $5$ balls are in different chambers is then $\left(\frac {11}{12}\right)^5$.  Thus the probability that your chosen chamber is non-empty is $1-\left(\frac {11}{12}\right)^5$

Answer (score 2):

If this is just a multiple choice question, then all those calculations are unnecessary. Namely, as $1\le X\le 5$, we have $1\le\mathbb E(X)\le 5$, which implies that the only solution that *might* be correct is C. Namely, A is bigger than $5$, and B and D are smaller than $1$.

Comment: Yes this is nice way to look at it but I am really intresting to know what is wrong in my calculations

Answer (score 2):

You are undercounting. I presume the idea with:

$$\mathbb P(X=k)=\frac{12\cdot 11\cdot\ldots\cdot (12-k+1)\cdot k^{5-k}}{12^5}$$

is this: the first ball can go into one of $12$ chambers, the second goes into one of $11$ remaining etc. - until we fill the $k$ chambers - and then the remaining $5-k$ balls go freely into those already defined $k$ chambers.

This neglects the possibility that the first $k$ balls don't all go into different chambers. For example, for $k=2$, you can have the second ball go into the same chamber as the first - and only the third ball goes to a different chamber. This event is not counted.

As a result, your probabilities are smaller than needed and don't add up to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

As have been already noted the probabilities you wrote down are not correct. The correct probability of $k$ from $n$ bins being non-empty after $m$ balls are placed into the bins is
$$
\mathsf P(X=k)=\frac{\binom nk {m \brace k}k!}{n^m}.
$$

Here the factor $\binom nk$ counts the number of ways to choose the $k$ non-empty bins, and the factor ${m \brace k}k!$ (where ${m \brace k}$ refers to [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)) counts the number of ways to distribute $m$ distinct balls between these $k$ bins.

It is the factor ${m \brace k}$ which is missing in your solution. The origin of the error was (as explained in a previous answer) unduly fixed order of placing the balls into the bins.